# Use variable from a different class for sorting a list: Android

Tags: android, sorting, collections

I have a class as,

```
public class ACompanyForSearchResult {
String companyName;
int likes;
}
```

And a list of it:

```
 ArrayList<ACompanyForSearchResult> List = new ArrayList<ACompanyForSearchResult>();
```

Here I am sorting it by name as,

```
/*To get the sorted value by name*/
private void sortName() {
Collections.sort(List, new Comparator<ACompanyForSearchResult>() {
     @Override
    public int compare(ACompanyForSearchResult aCompanyForSearchResult, ACompanyForSearchResult t1) {
            return (aCompanyForSearchResult.companyName).compareToIgnoreCase(t1.companyName);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Now I want the data to be sorted with respect to the city name which is in a different class BranchDetails as,

```
public class BranchDetails {
  String cityName;
}
```

I want to use this cityName to sort the same above "List". But I am unable to access the cityName into the previous class. I am pretty new to android so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Comparator:

```
   MyComparator extend  Comparator{
   Map<String ,String>  mMap=new HashMap();  key is  city, value is company


 public int  compare(BranchDetails  a , BranchDetails   b){
     if( mMap.get(a.cityName).compareto(mMap.get(b.cityName))==0){
     return a .cityName.compareto(b.cityName);
}else {
     return mMap.get(a.cityName).compareto(mMap.get(b.cityName));
}

}
```